# Using php to find the first element of an array and add it the class active to create a tab system with bootstrap.js

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to add an active class with PHP instead of using javascript.

But I probably broke the code somewhere.

I'm using bootstrap.js version 3 and I'm building my tabs using PHP because I need to use my tabs on the control panel in my app.

So essentially I didn't add any javascript or jquery so far, I'm just using the native functions for tabs in bootstrap.js (and jquery):

```
<?php foreach ($database as $item): ?>
    <?php
    if (isset($item['associations'])) {
        foreach ($item['associations'] as $value) {

            echo "<div class='modal' id='des_" . $value['des_id'] . "'>";
            echo "<div class='modal-sandbox'></div>";
            echo "<div class='modal-box'>";
            echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
            echo "<div class='close-modal'>&#10006;</div>";
            echo "<h3>Credit and values</h3>";
            echo "<h5>" . $value["designation_name"] . " - Credit: " . $value["designation_credits"] . "</h5>";
            echo "<ul class='nav nav-pills'>";

            if (isset($value['credits']) && !is_string($value['credits'])) {
                foreach ($value['credits'] as $credits) {
                    $first_element = reset($value["credits"]);
                    if (isset($value['credits'])) {
                        if ($first_element[4] == $credits[4]) {
                           echo "<li class='active'><a href='tab_" . $credits[4] . "' data-toggle='tab'>Identifier: " . $credits[0] . "</a></li>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<li><a href='tab_" . $credits[4] . "' data-toggle='tab'>Identifier: " . $credits[0] . "</a></li>";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            echo "</ul>";

            echo "<div class='tab-content clearfix'>";
            if (isset($value['credits']) && !is_string($value['credits'])) {
                foreach ($value['credits'] as $credits) {

                    if (isset($value['credits'])) {
                        if ($first_element[4] == $credits[4]) {
                            echo "<div class='tab-pane active' id='tab_" . $credits[4] . "'>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<div class='tab-pane' id='tab_" . $credits[4] . "'>";
                        }
                        echo "<div class='single-credit'>";
                        ?>
                        <?=form_open();?>
                        <?php
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $credits[4] . "'>";
                        echo "<div>Identifier: <span>" . $credits[0] . "</span></div>";

                        echo "<input name='edit_credits' type='submit' value='Edit' class='submit'>";

                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        ?>
                        <?=form_close()?>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

To explain my code I will start from the list:

Since it's a really complex array, I'm taking the first element with the reset function to add the active class only on that very element.

Then I added the href element to point to the id of the matching div later on, and then I close my list.

Later on, I create another loop and I use the id to match both the list and the div and I used the trick that I used before to add the class active only on my first element of my array.

Everything works except for the fact that, if I click another element of the list, the matching div won't work, the very first element of the array will keep the class active, so I can't switch beteween element.

I need to spot the error.

UPDATE:

The problem that I have with jquery, in this case, is that if I use a toogleClass for example like that:

```
$(".nav-pills li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $("#" + tab).toggleClass('active');
});
```

It won't be able to toggle properly the class on the first element, that one to which I added the class active with php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss to change the URL when click it, in the backend (PHP) you need to know where the user is, so, you check the "parameter" and mark active or not the current tab.

For example:

```
printf("<div class='tab-pane %s' id='...'>", $credits[4] == $_GET['tab'] ? 'active':'');
```

Comment: what if I would like to do in jquery?

Something like:

(".nav-pills li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".nav-pills li").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  tab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $("#" + tab).addClass('active');
  $("#" + tab).removeClass('active');
});

Comment: Could it be easier than dealing with a get request in php?

Comment: I can't really understand where to put your code right now, not sure why you used print

Comment: Could, but doing in the frontend (jquery) the user could see a screen flickering

Comment: printf** it is print format.. it is just an example, you can use: echo ... and concatenate as you do.

Comment: It doesn't find any get['tab'] (undefined)